# Asp Mvc Redirect Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am beginner in asp.net mvc. I have in the view `Home.cshtml`

```
<a href="" style="color:blue; margin-top : 30px;">Créer un nouveau compte</a>
```

I'd like to associate this link to this action in the controller `SuperController`

```
public ActionResult Admin_creation()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Admin_creation");
        }
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Url.Action` or `ActionLink`:

```
 @Url.Action("Admin_Creation", "Super");
```

Or:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Créer un nouveau compte", "Admin_creation");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text on screen", "Method name", "Controller name");
```

so going by your snippet above yours should read:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Créer un nouveau compte", "Admin_creation", "SuperController");
```